# Can't run python from shell within specific conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I have 2 cond envs.
First is base, it was created when I installed Anaconda.
Second was created by conda create env package package...

From PowerShell from base if I type "python" a python session begins. From the second - not, and nothing is done.

I am on Windows 7 Prof

Python on base is 3.7.4, on other env 3.11.0
Anaconda3 version is 2019.10 (works on Windows 7)

How can I run python from the second env?

Solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73932844/cannot-run-python-from-conda-env) doesn't work

UPD: When I activate conda envs from cmd, equally, from base python is started properly, but from second env thenew error is thrown:

```
api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll  is absent on PC, try to reinstall
```

UPD: I created a third env newenv with command

```
conda create -n newenv -c conda-forge python=3.11.0
conda activate newenv
python --version
```

This gives nothing. Python doesn't begin within this environment too.

Should I downgrade my env to python 3.7.9 for example?

UPD2: I also updated Powershell to 5th, created a new env with python 3.9. But still, I can't start python session from these envs.

Comment: The latest error suggest a nice solution. What happens when you create a third environment (`conda create -n yourenv python=3.11`), activate that (`conda activate yourenv`) and then check its python version (`python --version`)?

Comment: First command, enther python=3.11.0 gives:
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - python=3.11.0

Comment: Current channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Comment: Well, that makes sense as the `default` [channel](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/channels.html#what-is-a-conda-channel) does not [offer that Python version](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python) (it goes up to 3.10.8).You could specify the `conda-forge` channel to try installing it from there (it has [python up to version 3.11.0](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python)). [The manual](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/channels.html) explains how you can specify one or more conda channels.

Comment: python --version does nothing, as python does not work as previously mentioned. 
    (newenv) PS C:\Windows\system32> python --version<br/>
    (newenv) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda list<br/>
    # packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\newenv:<br/>
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel<br/>
    openssl                   3.0.7                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge<br/>
    pip                       22.3.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge<br/>
    python                    3.11.0          hcf16a7b_0_cpython    conda-forge<br/>

Comment: To answer you first question, creating of the new env does not change anything. So what's the nice solution then?

Comment: Should I downgrade python on that env?

Comment: Sorry, you're all over the place, it's hard to follow what you're doing. The comments are not for copy pasting logs. Please [edit] your question and add the commands and output to show what you're doing. Also, have you [read the system requirements](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html#system-requirements)? It mentions something on Windows and Python versions.

Comment: You're right. installing python 3.7.4, the same as in the base env soved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by creating the environment with:

```
conda create --name myenv -c conda-forge python=3.7.4 [other packages needed..]
```

python 3.7.4 is installed by default in Anaconda 2019.10 (the last compatible with Windows 7), but when creating othe envs - python 3.11.0 is installed by default, and it is not compatible.